# Linux/POSIX equivalent of Win32 API TerminateProcess in C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, posix, exit, terminate

On Linux/POSIX what's the equivalent of

```
TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0)
```

I want to be able to abruptly, unorderly terminate a program, no matter if I'm in a thread or not. I don't care about destructors, exit handlers or graceful termination, I just want to completely shutdown / kill the program.

Which system libraries must I include and which function / arguments must I use?

Comment: Sending a `SIGKILL` signal to the current process pid should do the same. https://linux.die.net/man/3/kill

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) function and `SIGKILL` signal:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TerminateProcess` Win32 API is equal to `kill` with `SIGKILL` signal.